# Accessing a SharePoint site using SharePoint mobile app will not load the Power App customized list form

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powerapp

We have a SharePoint online site collection >> and inside a custom list we have customized the list form using Power Apps. now if using the mobile browser or a PC browser >> we accessed this custom list and click on New button >> then the Power App customized form will load which is correct. but if we accessed the custom list using SharePoint mobile app (i am using IPhone 11) >> then the Power App customized form will not get loaded, and instead the SharePoint list form will be loaded... any idea, if there is a way to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mobile SharePoint App does not support rendering custom Power App forms. It's  not a bug and it's been working like this for the last 7 years. There is also no plan to introduce this feature to the SharePoint app.

The workaround would be to build an SPFx web part. SPFx webparts do render by the SharePoint app.